# Map push entry in Velocity Template E. 1.6

Tags: templates, hashmap, maps, push, velocity

I am using the Velocity Engine 1.6 and was wondering if it is also possible to put values to a map after it was created.

```
#set($myMap = {})
$myMap.push(K, V)
```

To update or pushing a new entry to the map? I‘ve tried it with push but it doesn‘t work for me...

Comment: It's put(), not push() ...

Comment: Uff, :facepalm: how could I oversee that... thanks.